# simplicial polytopes and convex hull

Tags: convex-geometry, polytopes, convex-hulls

In Ziegler's *Lectures on Polytopes* (7th printing), on page 8, it is said that "the convex hull of any set of points that are in general position in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a simplicial polytope", where "simplicial polytope" is defined slightly above as a "polytope, all of whose proper faces are simplices" (Ziegler uses "polytope" to mean "convex polytope").

I don't see how the statement about the convex hull can be correct. Take for example the pyramid with a square base in $\mathbb{R}^3$: one of its faces is definitively not a simplex.

Am I missing something?

Comment: The key is "points that are in general position". Note that the four points required to generate the square are four coplanar points - not general position... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_position

Comment: @HughDenoncourt: thanks, I didn't know the expression had a special meaning. I interpreted it as "any". If you convert the comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Good luck; polytopes are fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that "general position" is not the same as "arbitrary". The notion of general position depends upon context, but for this context, "general linear position" suffices.

A requirement for $n$ points to be in general linear position is that they be an affine basis for an $n - 1$ dimensional space. This is not satisfied by four points forming a square. The affine span of the four vertices is $2$-dimensional, not $3$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

Read "general posistion" as "not satisfying more affine dependencies than absolutely necessary". Or in other words:

- no two vertices on the same point
- no three vertices on the same line
- no four vertices on the same plane
- ...

The third points is not valid for the square based pyramid, as there are four points on a common plane.

And in general, if you have a $d$-dimensional face that is not a $d$-simplex, then this face contains at least $d+2$ vertices, and these all lie in a common $d$-dimensional affine space, in contradiction to "general position".